# INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE - how to clear cache?

Tags: caching, cookies, temporary-files

I recently updated a website, removing an old CMS and converting the website to static html files and changing the hosting server.

Everything is working fine, except that my client tells me that everyone at his office is getting the error : INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE

They all use Internet Explorer 11.

I cannot reproduce it, I've tried loading on IE on my side but I cannot get the error. After some googling, I've seen that this is probably due to cache/cookies.

I understand that we cannot force browsers to remove cache, but is there a way to fix this without telling the client that he has to delete the temporary files on all their computers?